# Flutter Firebase Storage Unable to upload File

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload a image  using the code below:

```
Future<String> uploadImageToFirebase(File imageFile) async {
  String fileName = basename(imageFile.path);
  Reference firebaseStorageRef =
      FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('uploads/$fileName');
  UploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(imageFile);
  var taskSnapshot = await uploadTask;
  String imageUrl = "";
  await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(
    (value) {
      // print("Upload Image Completed: $value");
      imageUrl = value;
    },
  );

  return imageUrl;
}
```

But I get the following error:

> E/StorageException(15399): Caused by: java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 400,    "message": "Your bucket has not been set up properly for Firebase Storage. Please visit 'https://console.firebase.google.com/project/imgs-e4332/storage/files' to automatically repair this issue and then retry. If the issue lasts longer than five minutes, you may have insufficient permissions to repair the project. You can check your permissions by visiting 'https://console.firebase.google.com/iam-admin/iam/project?project=imgs-e4332'."  }}

Comment: The solution is in the error msg itself. Please visit 'https://console.firebase.google.com/project/imgs-e4332/storage/files' to automatically repair this issue and then retry. Please try this and see if it works. 

Comment: @AsimBhadra It doesnt work, I visited it and there's an infinite loading icon

Comment: Have you set up your firebase storage properly and configured rules?

Comment: @AsimBhadra rules page is the one showing infinite loading spinner

Comment: rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}